What are some closest sounding numerals without any alternative pronunciation in a major modern language?
Most studies of numeral systems are about the base and not related to the confusability of how they sound too similar.
Numbers are too important in modern societies. Numerals are very context-independent in the modern world. Context rarely helps you to guess someone's street number, price of an unknown stock, ID number and etc.
Numerals in every modern language have the following characteristics: 1) sound distinct enough from each other (there can never be homophones in 1-9) 2) not too long (eg. ayisishiyagalolunye = 9 in Zulu).
Comparatively, numerals are significantly less important for hunter gatherer society/ primitive tribes. Lengthy numerals/ lots of near-homophones are definitely signs of a language not from the modern world because those languages do not have such evolutionary pressure to shorten the numbers and make it sound contrastive.

Confusability
Some experiments claim that generally confusability of consonant > vowel. My personal experience is confusability of consonant > vowel > tone. Tone is the strongest contrast to travel miles resisting the information being corrupted by noise. (eg. Silbo Gomero)
Near homophones:
Measured by the difference of "feature"
Consonants: manner, voicing, place etc
Vowels: height, backness etc
Tones/ Stress
Alternative pronunciations:
Here are some numbers that sound similar in different languages and there exists some alternative pronunciations to avoid confusion:
English
fifty VS fifteen
German
1 eins
2 zwei ("zwo" is an alternative pronunciation used to avoid confusion)
3 drei
(the numerals above differ at least by two segments)
Chinese
1 yī ("yao" is used to avoid confusion)
7 qī
(the two numerals differ at least by one segment and at least two features: manner, voicing)
So even for numerals differ more than "one feature", there could be an alternative pronunciation to avoid confusion.
I have compiled the list below (numerals 1-10) with limited online resource and it may not be accurate (please edit it). I would like to find out how close the numerals could sound alike without any alternative pronunciation. If they get to close then a new alternative pronunciation may emerge and replace the old one.
Most numerals differ by one segment below, with more than one feature. Most of them differ by consonants but not vowels nor tone alone. None of them differ by voicing only nor High VS Low tone which is very confusing:
Slavic: mostly 9 and 10
eg. Croatian: 9 devet 10 deset
Polish: 9 dziewiec 10 dziesiec
Russian: 9 devyat 10 desyat
Germanic: mostly 9 and 10
eg. Faroese: 9 niggiu 10 tiggiu
Icelandic: 9 niu 10 tiu
Luxembourgish 9 neng 10 zeng
Danish Norwegian: 9 ni 10 ti
Swedish: 9 nio 10 tio
Sinhala: 1 eka 2 deka 7 hatha 8 ata
[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QgOVg0hsGVM][1] <- I hear an “h” in 8 and it sounds so similar to 7.
Marathi: 6 sahaa 10 dahaa
Dari: 7 aft 8 asht 2 du 10 da
Ossetian 7 avd 8 ast
Persian 2 do 9 noh 10 dah 7 haft 8 hasht
Tajik 7 haft 8 hasht
Malayalam: 1 Ondru 3 moondru
Lomard: 6 ses 7 set (unaspirated coda)
French: 6 six 10 dix
Esperanto: 6 ses 7 sep
Dzongkha: 1 chi (H) 2 nyi 4 zhi (L) 8 ghe (L) 9 gu (H)
Tibetan: 2 nyi 4 shi 8 gye 9 gu 10 chu
Burmese: 1 tit 2 hnit 8 shit
Korean: 1 il 2 i
Hmong: 1 ib 2 ob
Mpi (Sino-Tibetan) 7 si (low, stiff tone) 4 si (high tone)
Fijian: 1 dua 2 rua
Sundanese: 8 dalapan 9 salapan
Guarani: 5 po 10 pa
Hungarian: 6 hat 7 het (accented)
Georgian: 10 ati 100 asi
Aymara: 1 Maya 2 paya
Chechen: 2 shi 4 di 9 iss 10 itt
Wolof: 3 ñett 4 ñeent
Acholi: 7 abiro 8 aboro (same tone)
Ewe: 3 etɔ̃ (MM) 5 atɔ̃ (MH)
Fon: 3 atɔn (L) 5 atɔ́ɔ́n (H)
Igbo: 5 ise (HH) 6 isii (MH) 10 iri (MH)
Tiv (Niger-congo): 2 uhar (HH) 3 utar (HM) 5 utaan (HH)

Many speakers from southern China don’t have retroflexes in their phonemic inventory and pronounce them as plain alveolars; this makes Mandarin 四 sì ‘four’ and 十 shí ‘ten’ distinguishable only by tone in their speech (sì vs sí).

Who told you numerals in every modern language… sound distinct enough… (there can never be homophones in 1-9)?
Ask anyone who's served in the army, navy or air force of any country which works with - or even against - any English-speaking army, navy or air force and unless they've forgotten their basic training, they will tell you that's not so.
Because people's lives can depend on it, NATO insists everyone uses 'Wun'; 'Thu-ree';'Fo-wer'; 'Fife'; 'Seffen'; 'Niner.'
All NATO's 32 members go along with the view, only two, six and eight might be safely distinct.

@RobbieGoodwin I told you numerals in every modern language is distinctive ENOUGH IN DAILY LIFE or it will develop alternative readings and become unstable. In case numerals are too important to confuse (everyone is involved in the army/aviation daily), your set of bisyllabic numerals will replace the current system. There are many cases of English/ Spanish numerals replacing base-4 base-20 indigenous ones cuz they are too long/ too hard to convert to decimal ones. Thx for the info of the military numerals.

Sorry… If I'd paid more attention to 'daily life', I might have skipped the NATO lecture and gone on to say that though it's neither a major nor a modern language, when 50 years ago I visited the isle of Orkney my native guide explained the numerals 1 to 5 in her Orcadian dialect were 'ying, ting, tethera, pethera, pop' - the spelling being my own attempt but distinguishing either pair must have needed very clear pronunciation, the more so since Orkney is one of the windiest places in the British Isles.
More…

Further, and slipping off numbers as such staying with linguistic change: when I learned the NATO phonetic alphabet that same 50 years ago, no-one failed to understand, eg, 'A for Alpha' or 'M for Mike' or 'Y for Yankee'.
Without the initials, many stumbled over 'Bravo' or 'November' or 'Zulu' alone and back then, hardly anyone ventured to use the tool themselves.
Hardly two generations on, everyone seems to follow letter-names without initials and nearly everyone uses them without a second thought.
Finally, more…

Further, finally. Sorry that went off topic and the point was the speed of a clear and simple change which seems to be applicable all over Europe and the English-speaking world, at least.
It would be easy to suggest the change came about because today so many more people telephone Customer Services when back then, much more business was conducted by snail mail.
In my view, that's not it, because my comments refer exclusively to talking on the telephone, not snail- or e-mail.
